# Do SIC Mosfets typically fail open?

Tags: mosfet, failure

I'm currently testing a PCB with a 650V SI Mosfet. When they fail due to voltage spikes or Over current, they fail short. This can cause extra work in testing because this can burn traces and cause other parts to fail. If I can use a device that fails open, It will save me from having to replace other parts and/or destroying the bare board.

Do all SIC Mosfets inherently tend to fail open or short or is it more of a case by case basis depending on which specific SIC Mosfet you choose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SiC tends to fail short just like Si. I have only ever had a single unit fail open, and that's because it exploded.

Fuses. Won't save the MOSFET but will help reduce auxilliary damage.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.